# How can I find the mime type without charset using "file"?

Tags: 20.10

I am going to use "file" to check file type of a buch of files. I need to get it to print output file mime type without charset part.

**My code:**

```
file dog.jpeg -i
```

**Output:**

```
dog.jpeg: image/jpeg; charset=binary
```

**What I want:**

```
dog.jpeg: image/jpeg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `man` page:

```
 -i, --mime
         Causes the file command to output mime type strings rather than the more traditional human readable ones.  Thus
         it may say ‘text/plain; charset=us-ascii’ rather than “ASCII text”.
--mime-type, --mime-encoding
         Like -i, but print only the specified element(s).
```

So by way of example:

```
$ file --mime dog.jpeg
dog.jpeg: image/jpeg; charset=binary

$ file --mime-type dog.jpeg
dog.jpeg: image/jpeg

$ file --mime-encoding dog.jpeg
dog.jpeg: binary
```

So you want `file --mime-type dog.jpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a clean way of doing but you can utilize the `cut` cmd.

```
file dog.jpeg -i | cut --delimiter=";" --fields=1
```

[cut del fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keWl9.png)